# Opening url via JavaScript, redirecting to ?results=aaa instead of results?q=aaa

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem. I try to use external search engine directly from my website but JavaScript seems to automatically change my URL and I don't know why.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
  var form = document.querySelector('#my-form'),
  text_field = document.querySelector('#results');

  function submitHandler(){
      window.open('https://myurl.com/results?q=' + text_field.value);
      win.focus();
  }

  // attach custom submit handler
  form.onsubmit = submitHandler;
```

And here is my html form code:

```
<form method="get" id="my-form">
<input type="text" name="results" id="results" value="" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

Why this code is redirecting to 
`https://myurl.com/?results=aaa` instead of `https://myurl.com/results?q=aaa` ?

Comment: Sounds like a server-side issue with routing, not a client-side issue. Also, if you want to work with the new window via the variable `win`, you need to declare and assign it with `var win = window.open(...)`. Lastly, you shouldn't need `win.focus()` in the first place unless something about the current window or the form's redirect page is grabbing focus.

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic because posted code works as it is supposed to and problem can't be reproduced. Most likely OP is experiencing some kind of server-side redirect.

Comment: Thank you Scott for the explanation. It's really helpfull!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default submit behavior:

```
function submitHandler(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open('https://myurl.com/results?q=' + text_field.value);
  win.focus();
}
```

The submit handler will be passed an event object. In this case `e`. Calling the method `preventDefault` will prevent default behavior and give you the desired result.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m5h132nj/

Comment: Shouldn't you have `var win = window.open(...)` if your next line is going to be `win.focus()`? And, how does this answer actually address the question or solve the problem? Maybe the OP wants to submit and open a new window?

Comment: @MrBlue This is not the correct answer. Your original code works as is See your unaltered original code working right here: https://jsfiddle.net/r9ftg0tn/2/ The form being submitted has no relationship to your `window.open()` statement.

Comment: **[Here' is a forked version](https://jsfiddle.net/srvsmwy4/1/)** of your Fiddle, only with `e.preventDefault()` taken out. Still works as it should and as it does with the OP's original code. `window.open()` is a completely separate operation from a form being submitted.

Comment: pretty sure you still want the prevent default in a real world situation

Comment: In a real world situation, this would be an AJAX call. There would be no form to submit and no submit event to prevent. Nevertheless, the form has zero to do with the new window. Whatever issue the OP is having with winding up at a different URL than his code specifies has got to be due to a server-side redirect.